# Defining cones and Turing cones

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, ultrafilters, determinacy

In *Set Theory* Jech defines a cone to be a subset of the Baire Space $\mathcal{N}$ of the form 
$$\operatorname{cone}(x_0)= \{x : x_0 \in L[x]\}$$
where $x_0 \in \mathcal{N}$. Jech then defines the equivalence relation $\equiv$ with 
$$x \equiv y \iff (x \in L[y] \land y \in L[x]).$$
In a similar fashion, in *Set Theory*, Schindler defines a Turing cone to be a subset of the Baire Space of the form 
$$\operatorname{cone}_T(x_0) =\{x : x_0 \leq_T x \}$$
where $\leq_T$ denotes Turing reductibility. Schindler then defines the equivalence relation $\equiv_T$ with 
$$x \equiv_T y \iff (x \leq_T y \land y \leq_T x).$$ 
They both want to prove essentially the same thing, which is:

> Assume $AD$. Then  if $A \subset \mathcal{N}$ is a $\equiv$(resp.
>   $\equiv_T$)-closed subset, then either it or its complement contains a
>   (resp.Turing)cone.

However, what they both do is pick for instance $\sigma$ a winning strategy for $I$ in $G_A$, and then show that $\operatorname{cone}(\sigma) \subset A$. Now of course, this isn't well defined, as $\sigma \notin \mathcal{N}$ (obviously).
 Now you can of course widen the notion of cones, but then the risk is losing a few characteristics of the filter you're trying to build (as for instance its non principality). 
How do you do this well, to solve this issue and not lose the properties that you require ?

Comment: What is $L[x]$, for people who don't have Jech's book in front of them?

Comment: Sorry, it's the smallest inner model containing $x$, where $x \in \mathcal{N}$ (actually the definition is for any $x$, but here it's in the Baire Space). The more rigorous definition goes through the same construction as for $L$ (the constructible universe) except the first step is with $cl(x)$, the transitive closure of $x$.

Comment: Strategies $\sigma$ are easily coded by elements of the Baire space and are usually identified with the corresponding element. (In a similar fashion, elements of the Baire space are usually called reals.)

Comment: Thomas, that's true but is the coding necessarily in $L[x]$ ?

Comment: It's recursive.

Comment: @Todd: Generally, for a set of ordinals $A$, $L[A]$ is the smallest transitive model of ZFC containing all the ordinals such that $A$ is an element of the model. It can be also be constructed in a similar fashion to $L$ by iterated definable power sets by augmenting the language to include a predicate which we interpret as $A$ (intersected with each stage of the construction). So if $x$ is a real number, or a subset of $\omega$, then $L[x]$ is the least such model with $x$ inside of it.

Comment: Maxtimax, what seems to be *the mistake*, though? Could you perhaps state it clearly?

Comment: The mistake was essentially that $\sigma$ is not in $\mathcal{N}$ and I hadn't thought of the fact that the coding of strategies through elements of  $\mathcal{N}$ was recursive, and that therefore it went smoothly both with Turing degrees and constructibles.

Comment: Also note that $L[x]$ is *not* the least inner model containing $x$ - the least inner model containing $x$ is $L(x)$. $L[x]$, in contrast, is the least inner model closed under $y \mapsto y \cap x$. However, for $x \in \mathcal{N}$, these notions agree, i.e. $L[x]= L(x)$.

Comment: Please consider choosing a more neutral title. Imagine you are the author of a textbook, would you be happy with a public question (which is more a statement, actually) on the internet "[your name] seems to make a mistake"?

Comment: @Stefan: For sets of ordinals the two models coincide.

Comment: Heinrich: you're right. I don't know if the new title is any better.. What do you suggest ?

Comment: It is not necessary to mention any names. Just include the mathematical objects that you talk about. (This is a general rule.)

Comment: @Asaf Yes, I'm aware. However, since $x \in \mathcal{N}$ is not a set of ordinals in Ralf's book, this seemed more relevant to OP. The underlying reason though, that $L[x] = L(x)$, is - as you hinted - that it can be recursively coded as a subset of $\omega$.

Comment: @Stefan: Generally, if $x\subseteq L$, then $L[x]=L(x)$. I don't know how Ralf defined the Baire space, but I suspect that it was done with functions from $\omega$ to $\omega$. So the same principle applies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simon Thomas already mentioned that a winning strategy can be recursively coded into a real. I thought it might be a good idea to write down one such coding explicitly:

Let $A \subseteq \mathcal{N}$ and let $\Sigma$ be a winning strategy for $G_{A}$ (say for player $II$, the other case is virtually the same). Then
$$
\Sigma \colon \bigcup_{n < \omega} \mathbb{N}^{2n+1} \to \mathbb N.
$$
Let $\mathbb P = \{ p_i \mid i < \omega \}$ be the increasing enumeration of all primes and let
$$
\Sigma^c\colon \mathbb N \to \mathbb N, \prod_{p \in \mathbb P} p^{n_p} \mapsto \Sigma(n_3, \ldots, n_{p_{(2 \cdot n_2 + 1)}}).
$$
Then $\Sigma^c \in \mathcal{N}$ is a recursive coding of $\Sigma$.